# How to press Ctrl + L keys using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to press Ctrl + L keys using JavaScript always when my website are loaded, my code is:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var e = $.Event("keydown");
        e.keyCode = 76;
        e.ctrlKey = true;
        $('body').trigger(e);
    });
```

but it doesn't work, please help - result: I want highligt address bar always when my website are loaded.

Comment: If websites were allowed to manipulate random menus in the browser, some sites would be very busy stealing personal information and installing bookmarks and malware.

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do with the URL bar exactly?

Answer (score 4):

This is just not possible, this feature is blocked by any decent browser since a long time ago.

As noticed in comments, that would be a *catastrophic* security weakness for any user.

(access to url toolbar would allow stealing history easily, and even opening some files on the client's computer, and going to dubious sites where worse could happen)

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate user action you can use chrome devtools protocol
There are some browser automation and testing frameworks which provides high-level api to easily achieve what you need.

Answer (score -3):

[Working filddle](https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=915ac3a8fa58)

you can use something like this with jquery

```
 $("body").keydown(function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

  if (code == 67) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      alert("Ctrl+C was pressed!!");
    }
  }
});

var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");

e.which = 67; // 'C' key code value
e.ctrlKey = true;

$("body").trigger(e);
```

Comment: How does the fiddle work? I don't see the bar highlighted at all on Firefox.

Comment: It presses ctrl + c
Check JavaScript code and you will get the function

Comment: And this presses ctrl + L key https://js-demo.com/index.php?ref=f567c6c4ca47

Comment: While this may emulate a given keypress, it doesn't trigger the action it's linked to in the browser, which is the intended outcome and ultimate goal. In some way, the problem is similar to trying to prevent pasting from clipboard by blocking Ctrl+V; it's just an interface for a feature, and one of several.